# Convexity proof under weaker assumptions

Tags: real-analysis, convex-analysis

Let $\phi(x)$ be a convex function of a positive real variable $x$. If it is twice differentiable is a trivial exercise to show that the function  $F(x)=x \phi\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)$ is convex. I am trying to prove the convexity of $F$ in the most general case. Any hint?

Comment: Lebesgue theory gives that convex functions are almost everywhere differentiable, with a monotone increasing derivative, and hence by more measure-theoretic results its derivative is almost everywhere differentiable. $F$ is then almost everywhere second differentiable and of positive derivative. I will link proofs if you require. It remains for you to show that almost everywhere positively second differentiable functions satisfy convexity (assuming this *can* be shown...) - one possible plan of attack

Comment: * I meant "and of positive *second* derivative". If it helps, the points at which $F$ is **not** differentiable form a countable set, so enumerable for the sake of a proof (and the set of points at which its derivative is discontinuous also form a countable set)

Comment: @FShrike thank you for pointing to the measure-theoretic results. I never put together them with convex analysis.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is true without any assumptions on differentiability, and can be verified directly using the definition of convexity:

For $0 < x < y < z$ is
$$
 F(y) = y \phi\left(\frac 1y\right) \le y \left\{
\frac{1/x-1/y}{1/x-1/z}\phi\left(\frac 1z\right)
+\frac{1/y-1/z}{1/x-1/z}\phi\left(\frac 1x\right)
\right\} \\
= \ldots = \frac{z-y}{z-x}F(x) + \frac{y-x}{z-x}F(z) \, ,
$$
using the convexity inequality for $\phi$ at the arguments $1/z < 1/y < 1/x$.

Comment: The proof shows that we have in fact an *equivalence:* $x \phi\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)$ is (strictly) convex *if and only if* $ \phi$ is (strictly) convex.

Comment: Or we note that the transformation is self-inverse, $xF(1/x)=\phi(x)$, for the “only if”.

Comment: @Milten: Yes, indeed.

Comment: Thanks. After your answer, the direct proof is trivial :) I still need additional work to become fluent with convex analysis...